# Display output console of a console program launch in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, process.start

I have a program console - **Program.exe** - which it's launched in a windows service. 
I use :

```
var Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.FileName = "Program.exe";
Info.Arguments = "args1  args2 etc.";
Info.CreateNoWindow = false;
Info.RedirectStandardError = true;
Info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Info.UseShellExecute = true;
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Proc = Process.Start(Info);
Proc.WaitForExit();
```

The **Program.exe** is well launched, but why the console not appears?

Comment: Because there's no desktop to host console window (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Actually, it is a bad idea - to display something from service or its child process. Create an application for monitoring and use IPC to send data from service to that application.

Comment: @Dennis: actually there *is* a desktop object, including a dummy display surface, and a window station object containing it.  It just isn't visible to the user.  You can still draw windows if you want to, it's just that nobody will see them. :-)  (If there were no desktop, you wouldn't be able to build a service as a console application, which would be inconvenient.  Also the dummy display surface makes it easier to run applications that weren't specifically designed to be services in a service context.)